# AWS copying one object to another

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, aws-sdk

I'm trying to copy data from one bucket to another using the ruby `"aws-sdk"` gem version 3.

My code is shown below:

```
temporary_object = @temporary_bucket.object(temporary_path)
permanent_object = @permanent_bucket.object(permanent_path)
temporary_object.copy_to(permanent_object)
```

However I keep getting the error `Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchKey: The specified key does not exist.` Which makes sense as the permanent bucket doesn't exist at this moment however I thought that using `copy_to` creates the bucket if it does not exist.

Any advice would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to make the destination bucket first.

Comment: I've already made the permanent bucket but when I copy the temporary object I want to place that in the bucket under the file path which is the `permanent_objects` key.

Comment: Can you give a bit more concrete example then?  Give an example source and destination as I'm not sure I'm completely following you.

Comment: I have 2 buckets a temporary one and a permanent one. At this point in my code the permanent_object has a key `/account_reference/<time_stamp>`. So when I copy the `temporary_object` to the `permanent_object` as far as I understand the `temporary_object` should be copied to the `permanent_object` so it should exist under `my-permanent-bucket/account_reference/<time_stamp>`. Just copying one object to another.